Raspberry Pi 4 Compute Module does not show output with HDMI display
I use Raspberry Pi 4 CM in bound with CM4-to-Pi4-Adapter. I've flashed a custom Yocto-image in that, using rpiBoot and RPi Imager for. Now I'm trying check my Raspberry's features, but when I try to connect it to Waveshark HDMI LCD (H) display (1024 X 600) there is nothing. The display once it powered on ligths grey then shows a some weird screen for a half of the second and finally stays black. The green light on the board glows brightly at the same time, but at some point it blinks very quickly and dims. I can see faint periodic blinks, like a pulsation, but I find it difficult to say which ones, short or long, as in the documentation.
I don't literally have any idea where should I find an error. The Yocto image I use just simple core-image-minimal with ssh and some Qt and GPIO's libraries included. The flashing was succesful as Imager says.
The screen output, sorry for blurry and overexposed photo
I've searched a lot of forums with same problems and done some steps from, like change a config.txt file, especially hdmi fields, but with some values of them I don't see even the screen I've uploaded.

Did you try different display? From the image posted: it appears your system isn't booting properly, it's stuck. Try boot into runlevel 3 first.

Thanks for your answer, rakib_23, but I don't understand you as I'm a beginner. I've tried the hp monitor, once it's connected, the green led starts blinking very quickly and does it endlessly. The thing is I do not have any access to the board, even ssh, 'cause I do not have the board's ip. What is runlevel 3?

Does the stock RPi OS (Raspbian) works for you or any other well known OS image? Try search how to pass runlevel 3 as kernel parameter.

Yes, I've tried Raspbian, and it's work fine. Now I will try some drivers for the display...

The answer was hidden at https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)_(with_case)
Just add this at the end of the config.txt:
config_hdmi_boost=10
hdmi_group=2 
hdmi_mode=87 
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0

And change in # Enable VC4 Graphics:
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d to dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
